# Get Object Custom Fields base on its Description or Help Text

Tags: apex, custom-object, custom-field, helptext

Is there a way to get the Object Custom Fields using the Field Description or Help Text..

Example:

I created a Custom Field and put a Description "Get Field". I can get all the 
Custom Field using the "Get Field" Description.

This is my apex now:

```
List<string> fieldlist = new List<string>();

fieldlist.addAll(Custom_Object__c.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the code to get the help text. For account.

```
Map<String,List<String>> allField = new Map<String,List<String>>();
      Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();    
        Map <String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = gd.get('Account').getDescribe().fields.getMap();

        for(Schema.SObjectField fieldAPI : fieldMap.values())
        {  
          //    Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfield = fieldAPI.getDescribe();
            System.debug('Help Text' + fieldAPI.getDescribe().getInlineHelpText());

        }
```

Just create a map or a list and add the field you want if the help text is correct. BGN...

Comment: How to get field description text?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, I think this should work:

```
String obj='Custom_Object__c';
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
Schema.SObjectType leadSchema = schemaMap.get(obj);
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = leadSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
String s = '';

for (String fieldName: fieldMap.keySet()) {
s += fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel() + '\t' +
 fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getInlineHelpText()+'\n';
}

system.debug(s);
```

You can put your condition inside the loop.